# Where does "open -b bundle_indentifier" get path to program from?

Tags: macos, bundle

For example i run in console "open -b com.apple.dt.Xcode", how does open determine what program to launch?

Comment: by looking at the bundle identifiers of the installed programs?

Comment: what is this command? It seems `open` doesn't have a `-b` option.

Comment: @halfelf: `man open` says `-b bundle_indentifier
         Specifies the bundle identifier for the application to use when opening the file`

Comment: @Thilo, i mean how it determine the path to program? i see "open" launches .app's from anywhere

Comment: You might find `LSFindApplicationForInfo()` in `LaunchServices/LSInfo.h` interesting...

Answer (score 3):

If you want  path to program, you can use applescript.

```
  osascript -e "POSIX path of (path to application id \"com.apple.dt.Xcode\")"
```

Answer (score 2):

Bundle identifiers are generally declared in an applications's app bundle `Info.plist`.  The values are identified and registered by various means in OS X and managed in the `Launch Services` database.  Read the [Launch Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/LSCIntro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH201-TP1) for detailed information, in particular, the section on [Application Registration](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCConcepts/LSCConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000999-CH202-BABEJFCD).