# Shell script for getting the path to program from its bundle identifier

Tags: macos, applescript

In a shell script I need to know the path to a program from its bundle identifier.

The last answer of [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13084324/where-does-open-b-bundle-indentifier-get-path-to-program-from) almost answers my question:

E.g. for getting the path to XCode the idea is to launch this AppleScript one liner:

```
osascript -e "POSIX path of (path to application id \"com.apple.dt.Xcode\")"
```

This displays the path, but it also launches the Xcode program.

Does anybody have an idea how to display the path *without* launching the program?

Any other method than using AppleScript is of course welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **Finder** to get the path:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to POSIX path of ((application file id "com.apple.dt.Xcode") as alias)'
```

---

Or, you can use a method of the `NSWorkspace` class (**macOS 10.6+**):

```
/usr/bin/python -c 'from AppKit import NSWorkspace; print NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().URLForApplicationWithBundleIdentifier_("com.apple.dt.Xcode").path()'
```